# Reinforcing a Subfloor Before Installing Tile

Tags: flooring, framing, floor

I want to reinforce my bathroom subfloor before I install Hardiebacker and tile.  The original construction is 4-in X 6-in beams 4-ft O.C. with 1 1/8-in T&G plywood spanning the beams; there are no joists.  Would it be sufficient to install 2x4 joists 12-in O.C. between the beams (the joists would be spanning about 44 1/2-in), or do I need to use a 2x6 (16-in O.C)?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please do not distract by the back and forth noises. The pattern 2x6 @ 16" o.c. will perform just as well as the beam to be replaced. Just need to make sure you have the same grade of wood, maintaining the 44.4" beam/joist span, and the unit weight of new material does not exceed the original by 33%. You can always do better, as suggested, to make 12" joist spacing at a negligible amount of add'l spending. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

I would install 2x6s at 12" OC if you are opening this up.   Why would you go through all of this trouble and not put 2 more "joists" down.

Just to be clear this isn't about the weight of the floor.   The is about the deflection of the weight on the tile when someone is walking across it.   You for sure cannot lay hardie and tile on 48" OC.   Sure the floor would work on install.   But if a 300 pound guy jumps... he might go through the floor... at best the tile is cracked.

This is from Hardie site

> The floor must be engineered not to exceed the L/360 deflection
> criteria (L/720 for natural stone)

The deflection level is based on the weight bearing properties of the joists and the weight on them and also the area in between the joists.   Hardie also says that 24" OC is the absolute minimum.   But it is basically impossible without pouring concrete to get to L/360 with 24" OC.   16" OC is the normal acceptable standard with 3/4" sub.   I am sure in this situation you can get by with 16" OC too but like I said if its about installing 2 more boards... why not?

Comment: Sound advice, I would do it if I am the OP. However, you didn't address why 2x4@12" does not work. From the perspective of deflection, I_4x6 = 4*6^3 = 864, D = 4w/864 = 0.0046; I_2x4 = 2*4^3 = 128, D = 1w/128 = 0.0078; I2; I_2*6 = 2*6^3 = 512, D = 1.33w/512 = 0.0026. Result D_2x4 > D_4x6 > D_2x6 (least deflection), so 2x6@16" works while 2x4@12" (largest deflection) doesn't.

Comment: @r13 - 2x4 at 12" does work according to rudimentary calcs.   We don't normally ever tile over 2x4 no matter the span because the rudimentary calcs do not take into account issues with the boards (knots, splitting, whatever).   Also 2x4 are very susceptible (2x6s kind of are too) to roll when supporting a weighted floor like stone or tile.   Given the span 2x6 is fine.   I really would prefer a 2x8-10.     I also feel like the deflection calculations are off based on subfloor type.   Given a strong 1" plywood... way less deflection than OSB.   (But not in standard deflection equations)

Comment: And yes you could deter roll with blocking.

Comment: You've proved my original judgement (stress over deflection) was wrong, as promised, I am going to withdraw my answer. But I don't know what "rudimentary calc" is about, I'll insist 2x6x16" will work, and 2x4x12" will be less sturdy than the original if all parameters and load remain the same.

Comment: @r13 - the deflection calculation is just  a starting point.   If you want to think about how young's modulus and elasticity of the materials it creates a more complex equation - often impossible to solve (anything is possible but almost impossible to gather the inputs).   Then you have to think about momentary load and force applied.   When speaking of carpet or vinyl planks or maybe even hardwood the deflection calculations can be done within ~15% degree of error.   Tile/thinset crack.   So the elstacity/bounce/warp matter more with a 300lb man walking or maybe jumping (on one foot!)

Comment: cont... now if you want to put up a sign of "please gently walk on this floor" or "walk on joist pattern if weight in room is over 800 pounds" then your calculations are fine.   But there is more to it then mathematics around joist, span, type of joist and offset OC.

Comment: Do you really understand my calculations? So far, I've provided everything, but you couldn't come up a single calc/number but bark in the air.

Comment: @r13 - I won't provide numbers because that is the whole point of my answer.   When an answer needs numbers I will provide them.   I won't be some moron that plugs in numbers to an equation and is like "dipty-do, go do this because the number is positive or great than this!"   That sounds like someone lacking skills and experience.   I can go over to JB and get the deflection level - using https://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/deflecto.pl... but as my answer points out, that is only one consideration.

Comment: cont...  I would suggest that you ask for a new site, Theoretical DIY.   Therefore people can take your equations with a grain of salt.   I just think it is funny that you have an equation for deflection and the stiffness of a floor that people will walk on but the force of people walking/moving isn't part of it.

Comment: Do you understand the word "equivalent replacement", if I have a beam/joist that is equivalent to, or better than, the original in both stress and deflection concerns, then why do I need to know the loading details? Provided the grade of the wood is the same for both the original and the replacement. Without my checks, I am sweating for your answer that does not have a theoretical backup. I don't want to take the credit, but the lone up-tick was by "me" to reward your persistence on this matter. Please stop now.

Comment: If this is going to continue, would either of you mind letting the rest of the class know which side you're arguing. It seems that @r13 has pointed out the the deflection of 2x4 is too great and so 2x4 will not work. Meanwhile DMoore has pointed out that even if 2x4 would work, he wouldn't use it given his experience. Are you both in contentious agreement?

Comment: @psaxton Not if he can provide the calculation. The **OP shall listen carefully, 2x4@12"** does not work. Period. Thanks for giving me another chance to clarify my stance.

Comment: @psaxton - my point is he messed up his math and the 2x4 falls into range of the deflection guidelines.    My other point is you do not ever put down 2x4 under tile.   Period period no matter what the AP calculus tells you.   The conversation is a newbie trying to interject advanced math into a really really easy problem.   2x6 at 12 OC should be the minimum.   I would pay extra $5 for 2x10 if they fit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is expanded to show the reasoning behind the call that the pattern - **2x6 joist @ 16" o.c. is to be used** in replacing the existing 4x6 beam, and why the 2x4 @ 12" pattern does not work.

Assume you are using the same grade of wood, and the beam/joist span length remains constant, then the pattern can safely carry the weight of the new flooring if an increase of flooring weight is less than 33% of the original. Otherwise, you shall seek advice from a structural engineer.

[image]

**Important Note: Don't try to follow the calc by yourself if you don't know the terms in it. It is a structural engineer's job.**

Comment: You indicate that the 2x4 on 12" spacing is "N.G." (I presume that's "not good") and that the 2x6 on 16" spacing is OK. What about the original 4x6 on 48" spacing? The Stress number is between the two - does where does it fall on the NG/OK scale? Also, does the 1-1/8" T&G plywood subfloor factor in? (Honest questions, I haven't a clue).

Comment: If the new flooring has the same weight as the original, 2x4 exceeds the stress in the 4x6 beam by (0.188-0.167)*100/0.167 = 12.5%, thus the arrangement is not good (N.G.). The 2x6 @ 16" has a stress (0.111-0.167)*100/0.167 = -33.5% lower than the 4x6 beam, so if the unit weight of the new flooring is no more than 33% heavier than the old, you should be safe using the pattern - 2x6 @ 16". Sorry for my mistake, and for causing confusion, hope this helps.

Comment: There was a mistake? Seriously, I didn't know and was wondering. You may want to include this info in the answer itself - makes it more obvious. Also, gives the OP an option of "leave it alone", along with conditions under which that would be acceptable.

Comment: @FreeMan I think you are freaking out by a single word without reading the whole content, including the revised answer (see text in bold) and my reply to the OP. I hope everybody has the guts to admit his/her mistakes and offer corrections.

Comment: Nope, no freaking out at all. I asked you an honest question because I didn't know the answer. You clarified. I thought your answer would be improved by including the clarification in the answer itself instead of leaving it just in the comment. I read your answer (edited 1 hour ago) with the edit, then asked my question (37 minutes ago). If you don't feel your answer would be improved by my suggestion, then don't edit it. I wasn't criticizing at all, just asking for clarification. I guess "mistake" referred to the original answer, not the edited one. My misinterpretation.

Comment: I am not sure what the drawings are of but this is not a good answer and I would delete it.    You should be calculating the deflection level not the weight bearing properties.   I am not even sure where this is going but its not right at all.

Comment: @DMoore Do your own calculation to challenge my accuracy then. For 4' (44.5") span, deflection or stress is more important?

Comment: @r13 - its deflection.   There isn't a manufacturer in the world that specs out anything more than 24" OC.   Even Hardie limits to 24" but then has a deflection guideline making it impossible to meet with 24" OC.    The load means nothing.   It is pretty much a given unless you are building the tile room to hold a 3 ton safe that if you meet the deflection guidelines you will meet load guidelines.

Comment: @DMoore For your curiosity: Bearing = P/A_b; Shear = V/A_v; Moment = M/S,  M = W*L^2/8, S = b*d^2/6; W = b_tr*w; Deflection = 5W*L^4/384E*I, I = bd^3/12.

Comment: @DMoore I've provided the necessary equations for your use (check a textbook if you care). In which, span L = 44.5", b_tr = 48", 12", and 16" (beam/joist spacing) respectively. As I said, I am done unless proven by you or others otherwise. Note, the original beam spacing (b_tr) was 48" o.c. while spaning 44.5".

Comment: @r13 - really trying not to get in an argument with you.   There are no math equations for minute framing of houses, there is just best practice and understanding.   Yes you could get into the math if you know ALL of the exacts, but you don't.   That is why when you go to a structural engineer to remove a loaded wall they over compensate the reference beam because they understand there is a large room for error.    When your math is close to the margin you don't know if its wrong or right and doing it is more confusing than knowing best practice.

Comment: @DMoore Just simply say you don't know how to do it. Don't mean to look down on you, as I've noted, it is a structural engineer's job. I've already provided more info than I like to, but it was for my own good as a sanity check, otherwise, another mistake could result. For committing back-to-back mistakes, I will hate myself for that.